# How to HTML-ize a String in Java

Tags: java, html, swing, newline, jlabel

I have a `JFrame` with a `JLabel`, and as my program runs, I want to change the text on the `JLabel` via `setText()`. I am well aware of the fact that in order to do a new line in a `JLabel`, one must put `<html>` tags around the String you wish to have a new line, and then within the tags, one must also place a `<br>` in order to make a new line.

However, I have run into a slight hiccup. Here is my MVCE.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class GearsWindow extends JFrame 
{

   public int x = 200;
   public int y = 200; 
   public int speed = 5;

   public String running;

   public JLabel l;

   public GearsWindow()
   {

      setSize(300, 200);
      setLocation(x, y);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      l = new JLabel();
      add(l);

      running = "RUNNING";

      updateLabel();

      setVisible(true);

   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      GearsWindow gw = new GearsWindow();

   }

   public void updateLabel()
   {

      String result = running + "<html><br ></html>" + speedStatus();

      l.setText(result);

   }

   public String speedStatus()
   {

      String result = "Speed - " + speed;

      return result;

   }

}
```

If you were to run this, you would end up with the result on the `JFrame` looking like this...

```
RUNNING<html><br></html>Speed - 5
```

Now, I know the easy way is to put `<html>` tags around every single `String`, however, with the amount of complexity that my program will have, it will become very difficult. I'm only showing an MVCE, the program is much bigger than this.

Is it possible to HTML-ize a String using a method or something?

Comment: Pahaha, forgive me, the re shouldn't be a newline before the speed - 5, apparently stackoverflow listens to my code, but not my actual application

Comment: don't put running outside html

Comment: @getlost Could you explain that with code? Like what does that look like?

Comment: <html>RUNNING<br>Speed - 5<html>

Comment: Swing components recognize HTML content by the <html> start tag in the beginning: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html

Comment: Call me crazy but it doesn't look like you've closed the `<html>` tag - you've got two opening tags.

Comment: @JonK whoops, let me fix that

Comment: @getlost I don't quite get your code, would that go within the ""? Because running is a variable, I don't want the word running to show up, I want the string value within running to show up

Comment: String running = "RUNNING";
         String result = "<html>"+ running +"<br >"+speedStatus()+"</html>" ;

         jLabel1.setText(result);

Comment: *'I am well aware of the fact that in order to do a new line in a JLabel, one must put `<html>` tags around the String you wish to have a new line, and then within the tags, one must also place a `<br>` in order to make a new line."*  I'm well aware that you are wrong about the `<br>`.  It is better to use CSS To specify the body width as 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void updateLabel()
   {

      String result = "<html>" + running + "<br >" + speedStatus()+"</html>";

      l.setText(result);

   }
```

If you want to prepare each string like that:

```
public String HTMLize(String temp)
{
    return "<html>"+temp+"</html>";
}
```

Comment: In what way? Is it still displaying the tags?

Comment: Yep, I get the exact same thing, I still see the html tags and br

Comment: So the output is `<html>RUNNING<br>Speed - 5</html>`?

Answer (score 3):

A generic method like this should help:

```
public String toHtml(String strPlain){
    if(strPlain==null || strPlain.trim().length()==0) return "";

    String res = strPlain.replaceAll("\\n","<BR/>");
    res = "<html>"+res+"</html>";
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Ah, this one is helpful as well! Thank you!